Force uninstall a cask with even more force than "normal extra force"
I'm trying to uninstall Autodesk Fusion 360 so I can reinstall cleanly.  I have casks installed for both the old & new names of the cask:
(base) [Wrench:~] % brew list | grep autodesk
autodesk-fusion
autodesk-fusion360

I'm not having much success, because the uninstall process tries to run its "streamer" script, and it fails, and that derails the whole process.  Here's me trying several incantations:
[Wrench:~] % brew uninstall --zap autodesk-fusion         
==> Implied `brew uninstall --cask autodesk-fusion`
==> Running uninstall script /usr/local/Caskroom/autodesk-fusion/latest/Install Autodesk Fusion.app/Contents/MacOS/streamer
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Caskroom/autodesk-fusion/latest/Install\ Autodesk\ Fusion.app/Contents/MacOS/streamer --process uninstall --quiet --silent --purge-incomplete` exited with 1.

[Wrench:~] % brew uninstall autodesk-fusion360         
Warning: Cask autodesk-fusion360 was renamed to autodesk-fusion.
==> Uninstalling Cask autodesk-fusion
==> Running uninstall script /usr/local/Caskroom/autodesk-fusion/latest/Install Autodesk Fusion.app/Contents/MacOS/streamer
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Caskroom/autodesk-fusion/latest/Install\ Autodesk\ Fusion.app/Contents/MacOS/streamer --process uninstall --quiet --silent --purge-incomplete` exited with 1.

[Wrench:~] % brew uninstall --zap autodesk-fusion360 
Warning: Cask autodesk-fusion360 was renamed to autodesk-fusion.
==> Implied `brew uninstall --cask autodesk-fusion`
==> Running uninstall script /usr/local/Caskroom/autodesk-fusion/latest/Install Autodesk Fusion.app/Contents/MacOS/streamer
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Caskroom/autodesk-fusion/latest/Install\ Autodesk\ Fusion.app/Contents/MacOS/streamer --process uninstall --quiet --silent --purge-incomplete` exited with 1.

[Wrench:~] % brew uninstall --zap --force autodesk-fusion360 
Warning: Cask autodesk-fusion360 was renamed to autodesk-fusion.
==> Implied `brew uninstall --cask autodesk-fusion`
==> Running uninstall script /usr/local/Caskroom/autodesk-fusion/latest/Install Autodesk Fusion.app/Contents/MacOS/streamer
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Caskroom/autodesk-fusion/latest/Install\ Autodesk\ Fusion.app/Contents/MacOS/streamer --process uninstall --quiet --silent --purge-incomplete` exited with 1.

[Wrench:~] % brew uninstall --cask --zap --force autodesk-fusion360 
Warning: Cask autodesk-fusion360 was renamed to autodesk-fusion.
==> Implied `brew uninstall --cask autodesk-fusion`
==> Running uninstall script /usr/local/Caskroom/autodesk-fusion/latest/Install Autodesk Fusion.app/Contents/MacOS/streamer
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Caskroom/autodesk-fusion/latest/Install\ Autodesk\ Fusion.app/Contents/MacOS/streamer --process uninstall --quiet --silent --purge-incomplete` exited with 1.

The streamer script does exist:
[Wrench:~] % ls -l "/usr/local/Caskroom/autodesk-fusion/latest/Install Autodesk Fusion.app/Contents/MacOS/streamer"
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 ken  staff  153168 Jun  7 09:38 /usr/local/Caskroom/autodesk-fusion/latest/Install Autodesk Fusion.app/Contents/MacOS/streamer*

What can I do to convince Homebrew that I really mean business?

Did you run brew doctor and fix any issues it reported?
